# display in DOM from $http from promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, http

Okay side  student have been learning js for about 8 weeks working on a final project not understanding how to display into the DOM from my requests. I need to display the summonerData into the dom with the matches... What am I doing wrong? Don't blow up my API key or I will have to get another one.

```
app.controller('ListController', ['$scope', '$window', '$http', 'LeagueService',                function($scope, $window, $http, LeagueService) {
    //$scope.interests = LeagueService.getInterests();

    $scope.searchSummoner = function () {
        LeagueService.summonerByName($scope.summonerText).then(function(responseData){
            console.log(responseData);
            //$scope.summonerObject = responseData.data['huriey'].id;
            let summonerId = responseData.data[$scope.summonerText].id;
            // debugger

            // make your second api call
            //  &seasons=SEASON2016
            return $http({
             method: 'GET',
             url:``
         });
     }).then(function (summonerData) {
            //  angular.copy(response.data.leagues, summonerCache);
            //  return response;
            console.log(summonerData);
            $scope.searchSummoner = function (summoner) {
        $window.open(`${summoner.data}`);
    };
    });
```

Comment: don't include your api key...

Comment: @Jacob Hurley There doesn't seem to be anything at all that even attemps to create DOM elements using the data you request.  Did you forget to include it?

Comment: I'm getting syntax errors from trying your code.

Comment: The code works perfect it brings in the summoner id and then makes a 2nd $http request to get all of the summonerData what I am asking is how to then populate the dom with summonerData

Comment: Expose the data to your scope: `$scope.summonerData = summoner.myField`. You can then access it from your view: `{{ $scope.summonerData }}` for example. Or `ng-model="$scope.summonerData"`

Comment: Okay so in my view I should $scope.summonerData? I tried that earlier and that didn't work unless am I not understanding?

Comment: Kind of. Your `summonerData` is whatever object was returned from your method. If it is exactly what you want in your page, you first need to expose it by doing something like `$scope.summonerData = summonerData`. If it is a full json object, then you need to be specific (`summonerData.myProperty` for example). At this point the way you have it, it is not part of your scope yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is, that you should use `then` only after a function call. You add it after the function define. You must do it as follow. then it works.

Define your function

```
  $scope.searchSummoner = function () { return $http(...)};
```

call your function and then you could use the `then`

```
$scope.searchSummoner().then(function (summonerData) {
            ...
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

With angular, you display through bindings. Here's a simple example of a binding:

`<input type="text" value="model.someProperty"/>`

or, you can do it this way:

`<span>{{ model.someProperty }}</span>`

I'd recommend you take some time and read up on angular and see how you can access data from your controller in your templates.